# как инициализировать поля в конструкторе С++

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор

столкнулся с проблемой инициализации полей в конструкторе класса

```cpp
class Circle {
private:
    Circle(double x, double y, double radius) {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        this->radius = radius;
        this->length = calculateLength();
        this->area = calculateArea();
    }
// дальше идут методы и куча ошибок что класс не имеет данных полей
```

выдает ошибку

> 'class Circle' has no member named 'x'

подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема, буду очень благодарен за ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, компилятор говорит: В классе `Circle` не объявлено поле `x`.
А еще, конструктор приватный, что приведет ко еще одной ошибке компиляции.

```cpp
class Circle {
public: // сделать конструктор публичным
    double x;
    double y;
    double radius;
    double length;
    double area;
    Circle(double x, double y, double radius) {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        this->radius = radius;
        this->length = calculateLength();
        this->area = calculateArea();
    }
    // ...
};
```

Comment: А  зачем тут this? В последнее время не первый раз встречаю...

Comment: @FonarSiny [указатель на текущий объект с которым метод работает](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this)

Comment: я знаю что такое`this`. Вопрос в том, **зачем** он здесь. Очевидно, что в данном случае `x` будет всегда полем класса, а не каким-то ещё левыми `x`.